# Connect C wire to Furnace

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I have a Lenox Merit system in the house. I am trying to install Nest E thermostats and want to do it with a C wire. I noticed an unused Blue Wire (pic attached) at the thermostat location and then in the attic saw that the Blue wire is not attached to the C at the circuit board. There is another wire in the C. Do I just add the blue wire in the same location ?

[image: Attic]

[image: Thermostat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Go ahead

The terminal blocks on HVAC control boards can generally handle two wires per terminal, so landing the C wire to your thermostat on the furnace board's C terminal directly is fine.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I was hoping for. I added the wire straight to the terminal and tested the current thermostats, everything is fine. Now on to the nest